# python adding unique items to a huge table

Tags: python, database, sqlite, mysql-python

I have a very large list of items (10M+) that must be put in a table with three columns (Item_ID,Item_name,Item_count)

- The items in the table must be unique.
- We are adding the items one by one.
- When each new item is added, we need to check:

  - if it is on the table, update its count +1, and retrieve its ID
  - if not on the table, insert it in the table, assign it an ID and set its count to 1

I have tried with different database implementations (MySQL and sqlite, python shelve, and my own flat file implementation), but the problem is always the same: the more rows there are on the table, the more lookup operations will be needed (for a table 10,000 rows, will need to do around 10,000*10,000 at least lookups for the following 10,000 items.

Indexing the database may sound a good idea to optimize, but my understanding is that the indexing is done after the bulk of the data is inserted, not updated with each insertion.

So, how can we add such large number of items into a table the way described?

Comment: "Indexing the database may sound a good idea to optimize, but my understanding is that the indexing is done after the bulk of the data is inserted, not updated with each insertion": once the index is created, it is updated in most databases I know of **after** each insertion.

Comment: yes, but it will need to check all other indexed rows, right?

Comment: No, it will check the index. Think of it like this: you take a hash of the item name, you use the hash value as the row number in the index, the index row lists all the rows in the main table having item names with the same hash, you then only need to check those rows (**if any**) for equality. Hence, you don't need to check all rows every time, just a subset (or none at all). The whole point of indexing is to avoid "full table scans".

Comment: When you add an item, do you have it's ID or just the name?.  Or is the ID provided by the database?

Comment: If the data could fit in memory, a `collections.defaultdict` would be the natural Python structure.  For something file based, I wonder about using such a dict as a cache.

Answer (score 0):

you can use set() to check if that item is already on the list
im assuming that you have a list of list(w=[[id,name,count],[id,name,count],..])

```
r=[e[1] for e in list]   <--- this will create a new list that only contains the names

if(len(set(r+item[1]))== len(set(r))){  <-if this is true then the item is on list
     list[list.index(item)][countIndex]+= 1  <-- count +1
     list[list.index(item)][idindex]   <-- to retrieve id
}else{
     list=list+[id,item-name,count] <-- this will add the item 
}
```

if you have the list on your database its the same, just use queries the get and set the info.

to set the id you can search the last item id and set +1 like this

```
list=list+[list[len(list)][id]+1,item-name,count]
```